# Java. log4j и обработкой исключений

Tags: java

Привет.

Есть метод, который бросает исключение:

```
throws ClientProtocolException, ServerException, 
    UnsecuredConnectionAttemptError, IOException{
```

Как регистрировать эти исключения в журнале с помощью log4j ?

Answer (score 1):

Перехватит его в `catch` и записать в лог с нужным вам уровнем.

```
// в начале класса
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(<имя класса>.class);


try {
    // код 
} catch(ClientProtocolException | ServerException | 
UnsecuredConnectionAttemptError | IOException ex) {
    logger.error("Что-то пошло не так", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Очень много блоков try catch получится. Думал есть возможность как-то по-другому сделать.

Comment: @Slaine оберните только самый верхний метод. Будет ровно один блок.

Comment: Не понял, как это сделать?
У меня два класса, в первом несколько методов, которые бросают эти исключения и public класс тоже бросает эти исключения.

Comment: @Slaine у вас есть main метод? Это настольное приложение?

Comment: да, есть main метод. Настольное.

Comment: @Slaine вот и оберните тело метода в try/catch.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы активно используете потоки, то есть возможность подвесить обработчик исключений на поток. Тогда, если во время работы возникает исключение и оно не обрабатывается, то его можно будет перехватить и сделать какую то полезную работу, например сделать запись в лог.

Выглядит это следующим образом:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        method();
});

thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
     @Override
     public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        //логирование сообщений об ошибках
     }
});

thread.start();

private static void method(){
    // что то там кидается
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но это пока слишком круто для меня. Потоки не использую.